# How to query against month and day against Joda LocalDate in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, jodatime

How does one efficiently perform a query based on the month and day components of a Joda LocalDate object when the persisted data type is Binary(255).

What I am trying to accomplish is to find 'customers' whose dateOfBirth (LocalDate) occurs on todays date(LocalDate).

It seems not possible with Criteria queries, and falling back to HQL struggles with a query such as

```
def startDate = LocalDate.now()

      def entries = Customer.executeQuery("SELECT c FROM Customer AS c " +
              "WHERE DAY(c.dateOfBirth) = DAY(:today) AND " +
              "MONTH(c.dateOfBirth) = MONTH(:today) ",[today:startDate])
```

because of the LocalDate type.

Answer (score 0):

use `sqlRestriction`:

```
def startDate = LocalDate.now()

def entries = Customer.withCriteria{
   sqlRestriction 'DAY(dateOfBirth) = DAY(now()) AND MONTH(dateOfBirth) = MONTH(now())'
}
```

which allows you to mix SQL with Criteria. `day()`, `month()` and `now()` functions shall be present in your DB, but you have to check that

Comment: Good idea, thought that would work but still getting a problem.  
Cannot parse "DATE" constant "aced0005737200176f72672e6a6f64612e74696d652e4c6f63616c44617465fffff804d3e4ebb50200024a000c694c6f63616c4d696c6c69734c000b694368726f6e6f6c6f677974001a4c6f72672f6a6f64612f74696d652f4368726f6e6f6c6f67793b78700000004d110ac400737200276f72672e6a6f64612e74696d652e6368726f6e6f2e49534f4368726f6e6f6c6f67792453747562a9c811667137502703000078707372001f6f72672e6a6f64612e74696d652e4461746554696d655a6f6e652453747562a62f019a7c321ae30300007870770500035554437878";

Comment: I think the fundamental issue is the PersistantLocalDate stored by Joda is not a SQL timestamp therefore the SQL functions for date manipulation are no longer a valid option...   If I can convert from Jodas binary form to a timestamp then I should be on the right path...

Comment: how the joda date fields look like?

Comment: Well in the Domain it is a LocalDate,   in the database(h2) it is held in a binary, what appears to be 223 bytes.  

I don't think there's much I can do, as this is Jodas own format it's storing.. SQL alone will not be able to do anything with it.     Wish I knew this before using LocalDates.

Comment: then I would switch to plain Date, providing the joda getters and setters if necessary. Otherwise you can forget about querying

Comment: It looks that way but with data in production I was really hoping to avoid this.  LocalDate has always been my choice of field type for things like a birth date.  I'm thinking of introducing an additional calculated field based on just the MMDD portions to enable fast exact match searching.